# How to select last 7 days results from mysql (with custom data field)?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

I need to select data from mysql for last 7 days. I have field named 'date' and which have values in mm.dd.yy format. 
So i tried to find special mysql request to do that, but its not work with my field, i gues that beacause date in wrong format.
How i can do that from php (use some variable to get mysql entries), or with custom select query ?

Comment: use explode to make it proper format and then try again what have you tried before.

Comment: it's a really poor practice to store your date as a varchar and in mm.dd.yy format. Stick to the convention and make it DATE or DATETIME format and store it in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator how can i make date field in format which i need? And will it work with data manipulations in sql?

Comment: I'd suggest you to seect type as date in yy-mm-dd format. And every time you fetch it, you can format it as per your need(Maybe write a function to convert date in your desired format and call the function every time). This way, in future, if you need multiple date formats for different users, it will be easy to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your [idiosyncratic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiosyncrasy) date format to a standard `DATE` value. An expression like this will do the trick

```
 STR_TO_DATE('07.17.97', '%m.%d.%y')
```

Then you can say

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m.%d.%y') >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

in your query to filter items with `date` values starting a week ago.

But, if you have a lot of rows to filter you will have poor performance:  this kind of WHERE clause is not [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Comment: I change my date field type to DATE, and reformat it on front-end side to comfort view. And its solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

First read your table and change the date format

```
$new_date_format = date('Ymd',mktime(0,0,0,substr($date,0,2),substr($date,3,2),substr($date,6,2)));
```

After that you can make comparisions

Comment: This would defy the whole purpose of using SQL - you would need to fetch the entire table and then search through it using PHP code. What do you mean, inefficient?

Comment: Depends on how large the table is!

Comment: Hmm, no... I disagree.